# Simple Mac Bash Script (Find/Replace)

Tags: macos, bash, safari

First, any support and help on this is largely appreciated.

I'm trying to write a simple Bash script (completely new to this) to replace a file in a given directory.

Basically, I need to write a script to replace the safari preference file, here's what I have..and what's not working for that matter:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /Files/ -iname "com.apple.Safari.plist" - print0 | xargs -I{} -0 -1 cp file /Users/{}/Library/Preferences
```

It errors out with the following:

```
find: -: unknown option
xargs: illegal option -- 1
```

Any thoughts, ideas, are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand what exactly you want to accomplish with this. As I understand, you would have this "com.apple.Safari.plist" in /Files/, is that correct?

And then you want to get this file into some place that, I assume, overwrites Safari's current plist file. Assuming you take ghostdog74's correct advice and remove the space between `- print0`, thus turning it into `-print0`, and then remove the `-1` from xargs, as it doesn't exist, this is what would happen:

`find` would find your file in /Files/, and `xargs` would run this:
`cp file /Users/com.apple.Safari.plist/Library/Preferences`; It would then die, since it would not find a file called "file" or a directory named "/Users/com.apple.Safari.plist/".

That's most likely not what you want. :)

If you just want to copy the file to somewhere, why don't you just do `cp /Files/com.apple.Safari.plist ~/Library/Preferences/` ?

Do you really need `find` and `xargs` in this case? Could you clarify?

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. You could accept the answer, though, so as to prevent other people from trying to post further answers when they're not needed. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

No space between `- print0`. and since `-1` is not an option, remove it and see.

```
find /Files/ -iname "com.apple.Safari.plist" -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 cp file /Users/{}/Library/Preferences
```